# Get list of CollectionView return Object and put in IIList of Model in xamarin.form

Tags: c#, xamarin, collectionview

In Xamarin,Try to get list of items in collectionView

My Model is

```
   public class DrugModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsUsed { get; set; }
    public int NumberUsed { get; set; }
}
```

] bind CillectionView to List that returview Api, and when debugger arrive to my change event cant get data and put on my List

```
 [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class DrugMissionPage : ContentPage
{
  
    public IList<DrugModel> SelectedDrug;

    public DrugMissionPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void listDrug_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var  selectedDrugList =e.CurrentSelection ;
        var tyy = selectedDrugList.ToList() as IList<DrugModel>;

        foreach (var item in selectedDrugList)
        {
            SelectedDrug.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

And this is my View

```
 <CollectionView                  
          x:Name="listDrug"
            VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
        SelectionMode="Multiple"
            ItemsLayout="VerticalList" SelectionChanged="listDrug_SelectionChanged">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Frame Padding="10">
                        <Frame BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"  HasShadow="True" CornerRadius="10" Padding="10" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Default" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,10,10,0"></Label>
                               
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </Frame>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

    </CollectionView>

}
```

How can I fill

```
 public IList<DrugModel> SelectedDrug;
```

When debugger pass from

```
        var tyy = selectedDrugList.ToList() as IList<DrugModel>;

    foreach (var item in selectedDrugList)
    {
        SelectedDrug.Add(item);
    }
```

**"tyy"** will be null

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Cast<class>` to convert List to List.

**Change:**

```
var tyy = selectedDrugList.ToList() as IList<DrugModel>;
```

**To:**

```
 var tyy = selectedDrugList.Cast<DrugModel>();
```